# Mod_rewrite Search form results

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a search form that uses URL friendly, but in the search results because of the URL is not getting the get values from the URL, above I leave link of the URL and the code from .htaccess, maybe someone can figure out what is the error/problem.

http://www.domain.com/en/jobs.php?Keywords=&Location=2&Category=

```
RewriteRule ^(es|en|pt|fr|pl|de|ro|it)/jobs.php?Keywords=(.*)&Location=(.*)&Category=(.*)$ jobs.php?lang=$1&Keywords=$2&Location=$3&Category=$4
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work as long as the parameters in your query string always come in the same order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Keywords=(.*)&Location=(.*)&Category=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(es|en|pt|fr|pl|de|ro|it)/jobs.php jobs.php?lang=$1&Keywords=%1&Location=%2&Category=%3 [L]
```

You need to look specifically at the query string and apply your regex capture groups there. You can then use them in the rewrite with the back reference character: `%`

Comment: Would be nice if the downvoter could explain the reason!

Comment: thanks @arco444 , im kind of new at htacess regular expressions, but what do you mean with "apply your regex capture groups", could you give me a example?

Comment: A capture group is that within parenthesis `(...)`. The regex engine will store matches within parenthesis as variables. In the case of the `RewriteCond` there are three that perform a *greedy* match `.*`. These are available in apache as `%1`, `%2`, and `%3`. The `RewriteRule` contains one group which contains your lang matches. This is available as `$1`. You can combine all four in the rewrite as shown. Does that help?